# How can I search for specific static memory address in iOS games some thing like amount of damege and other

Tags: ios

How can I search for specific  static memory address in iOS games some thing like amount of damege and other Thing that don't have vaule in Gameing 
I use Ida put its not helpful cause it not show you the statice memory address

Comment: HI new user!   Do you mean, when you are **programming** a game?   Which game do you mean?

Comment: Your own app or other games downloaded from the appstore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to hack existing games by twiddling bytes similar to what Game Genie did on old video game systems, good luck with that.  Besides the fact that iOS apps use dynamic memory allocation for pretty much everything, iOS also incorporates address space layout randomization, which means even ostensibly static storage probably won't be in the same location in consecutive launches.

The only approach that would even stand a chance of working would involve injecting code that performs introspection of the classes using Objective-c runtime calls.  And even if you do that, there's no guarantee that such hacks will be possible or practical in iOS.